# Expand HStack within List to go end to end but not top to bottom so it looks like there are wider spaces between items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to create a list and expand the space between the rows, while keeping them the full width, but I seem to be having some challenges. I think the approach is to make the HStack within the list expand horizontally from end to end and try to narrow top and bottom. I thought a frame modifier would do this but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
    NavigationView() {
        List(caseList) {caseItem in
            HStack {
                
                
                Image(systemName: "folder.fill.badge.person.crop")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                    
                    Text(caseItem.alias)
                    Text("# team members")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .background(Color.green)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .badge(Int.random(in: 0..<5))
            .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.cyan, edges: .all)
            .listRowSeparator(.visible)
            .listRowBackground(Color.orange)
            .frame(
                maxWidth: .infinity,
                minHeight: 0,
                maxHeight: .infinity,
                alignment: .topLeading
            )
            
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
    .onAppear() {
        loadCases()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Cases")
```

I would also like to delete the gap between the list items and cases at the top.

**UPDATE**

I added a 2nd image to show, in red, what I would like the green shape to cover. I guess my goal is to make them look a little more like independent items with additional information and bigger spaces between them. This should not be an exhaustive list and in most occasions people will only have one, so I am trying to make them of substance. I was toying with expanded/collapsed ones so if you only had one, it would be expanded and not look so lonely.

Comment: add `padding()` to your `HStack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the goal correctly, here it is (tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5)

[image: demo]

```
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "folder.fill.badge.person.crop")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

                    Text(caseItem.alias)
                    Text("# team members")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .badge(Int.random(in: 0..<5)).padding(.horizontal)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
            .background(Color.green)
            .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.cyan, edges: .all)
            .listRowSeparator(.visible)
            .listRowBackground(Color.orange)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly, you want to space out your Items inside of your list?

in this case, you can add some **padding(EdgeInsets(top: *15*, bottom: *15*))**

"change the *cursive* text to the values that you want"

this would look something like this:

```
NavigationView() {
    List(caseList) {caseItem in
        HStack {
            
            
            Image(systemName: "folder.fill.badge.person.crop")
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                
                Text(caseItem.alias)
                Text("# team members")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .background(Color.green)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .badge(Int.random(in: 0..<5))
        .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.cyan, edges: .all)
        .listRowSeparator(.visible)
        .listRowBackground(Color.orange)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, bottom: 15))
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .topLeading
        )
        
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
}
.onAppear() {
    loadCases()
}
.navigationTitle("Cases")
```

Hope that helped you! if you need anymore help, you can contact me over on GitHub or Discord! (Discord on my profile)